# keras (tensorflow backend) conditional assignment with K.switch()

Tags: if-statement, tensorflow, keras, switch-statement, backend

I'm trying to implement something like

```
if np.max(subgrid) == np.min(subgrid):
    middle_middle = cur_subgrid + 1
else:
    middle_middle = cur_subgrid
```

Since the condition can only be determined at run-time, I'm using Keras syntax as following

```
middle_middle = K.switch(K.max(subgrid) == K.min(subgrid), lambda: tf.add(cur_subgrid,1), lambda: cur_subgrid)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
<ipython-input-112-0504ce070e71> in col_loop(j, gray_map, mask_A)
     56 
     57 
---> 58             middle_middle = K.switch(K.max(subgrid) == K.min(subgrid), lambda: tf.add(cur_subgrid,1), lambda: cur_subgrid)
     59 
     60             print ('ml',middle_left.shape)

/nfs/isicvlnas01/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in switch(condition, then_expression, else_expression)    2561         The selected tensor.    2562     """
-> 2563     if condition.dtype != tf.bool:    2564         condition = tf.cast(condition, 'bool')    2565     if not callable(then_expression):

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

`middle_middle`, `cur_subgrid`, and subgrid are all `NxN` tensors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that with `K.max(subgrid) == K.min(subgrid)` you're creating a *python boolean* comparing two tensor objects, not a *tensorflow boolean tensor* containing the value of the comparison of the *values* of the two input tensors.

In other words, what you have written will be evaluated as

```
K.switch(False, lambda: tf.add(cur_subgrid,1), lambda: cur_subgrid)
```

instead of

```
comparison = ... # Some tensor, that at runtime will contain True if min and max are the same, False otherwise. 
K.switch(comparison , lambda: tf.add(cur_subgrid,1), lambda: cur_subgrid)
```

So what you need to do is to use [keras.backend.equal()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/equal) instead of `==`:

```
K.switch(K.equal(K.max(subgrid),K.min(subgrid)), lambda: tf.add(cur_subgrid,1), lambda: cur_subgrid)
```

Comment: PS: I'm sorry I can't test this now, so I hope it does work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly the reason.