# Is there a way to selectively connect layers with Keras TensorFlow?

Tags: keras, layer, tensor, autoencoder, transfer-learning

I have an autoencoder type tandem network consisting of a pre-trained forward DNN (weights frozen) taking the output from an untrained inverse DNN. I wish to have a direct mapping between the models such that the output layer of the first network represents the input tensor to the second. I am currently using Keras API sequential model to add dense layers, however, these are fully connected.[I've included a diagram here (please have a look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvGDB.png)

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
(`#tandem architecture (with weights loaded from pre trained model)
Tandem = keras.models.Sequential()
Tandem.add(Dense(2, name = 'CIE_input'))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'IH1'))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'IH2'))
Tandem.add(Dense(3, name = 'Iout')) #need to feed a 3 layer input to FDNN
#FDNN for prediction:
Tandem.add(Dense(3, name = 'input',trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH1', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH2', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH3', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH4', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH5', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH6', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH7', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH8', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH9', trainable = False))
Tandem.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', name = 'FH10', trainable = False)) 
Tandem.add(Dense(2, name = 'output')) # output layer (predicted colour (CIE))
Tandem.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mean_squared_error','accuracy'])
#train the model for one batch to initialize variables (needed before loading weights by name)
Tandem.train_on_batch(y_train[:1], y_train[:1])
#load weights from pre-trained model 
Tandem.load_weights('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Models/FDNN_Weights.h5', by_name=True)`
```

In addition, I would like to make the connection between the two networks fixed and not allow rescaling. I am new to TensorFlow and Keras (as well as StackOverflow) so I'd be very appreciative of any advice on how to do this simply.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Functional API in `tf.keras`. It helps you to create models with several inner connections and multiple inputs and outputs.

- [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) is the official TensorFlow document.
- Also, I recommend these posts ([1](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/) , [2](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/28/3-ways-to-create-a-keras-model-with-tensorflow-2-0-sequential-functional-and-model-subclassing/) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451045/cnn-model-conditional-layer-in-keras) ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in my code; I had not defined the input shape to the sequential model. I have now removed the layers named 'input CIE' and 'input', defining the input dimensions of layers 'IH1' and 'FH1' to be 2 and 3 respectively. This proper model definition allows for the models to be connected directly, forcing the output of the inverse model to converge to 3 values.