# Keras conditional passing model, training and prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset consist of binary class distribution `cat and dog`. In each class, there are `four subclasses (breeds of cat or dog)`. So, my data directory structure is

[image]

Now, I am facing problem two make a `two-stage Neural Network`. In the `first stage`, the model will perform `binary classification (cat or dog)` and in the `second step`, the model will perform `multi-class classification (breeds of dog or breeds of cat)` based on the **first stage model output**. A pictorial view of my model is,

[image]

***How can I implement this in Keras?***

**Note:** Seperate Code implementation of Stage 1 and Stage 2 & dummy data generator of these two satge is,

**import libraries:**

```
from keras import metrics
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist,cifar10
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.utils import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
```

data of two-stage model are

```
num_images = 200
# binary data generator
X_train_2_class = np.random.random([num_images, 32, 32, 3])
y_train_2_class = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=num_images)

# half of images are cat & half of them are dog

# cat breeds data 
X_train_4_cat_breeds = np.random.random([num_images//2, 32, 32, 3])
y_train_4_cat_breeds = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=num_images)
# dog breeds data     
X_train_4_dog_breeds = np.random.random([num_images//2, 32, 32, 3])
y_train_4_dog_breeds = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=num_images)
```

**Models of Stage 1 and Stage 2**

```
img_rows,img_cols,number_of_class = 32,32,2
number_of_cat_breeds, number_of_dog_breeds = 4,4

input = Input(shape=(img_rows,img_cols,3))

#----------- 1st Stage Model ------------------------------------
conv_01 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',name = 'conv_01') (input)

skip_cat =  conv_01

conv_02 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',name = 'conv_02') (conv_01)

skip_dog =  conv_02

flatten_first_stage_model =  Flatten() (conv_02)
Output_main_model = Dense(units = number_of_class , activation = 'softmax', name = "Output_layer")(flatten_first_stage_model)
# #----------- 2nd stage Conditional  Cat model ------------------------------------ 
conv_03 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',name = 'conv_03') (skip_cat)
flatten_cat_model =  Flatten() (conv_03)
Output_cat_model = Dense(units = number_of_cat_breeds , activation = 'softmax', name = "Output_layer_cat")(flatten_cat_model)
# #----------- 2nd stage Conditional  Dog model ------------------------------------ 
conv_04 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',name = 'conv_04') (skip_dog)
flatten_dog_model =  Flatten() (conv_04)
Output_dog_model = Dense(units = number_of_dog_breeds , activation = 'softmax', name = "Output_layer_dog")(flatten_dog_model)
# --------------------------- Models of 1st & 2nd stage -----------------------
model_at_stage_1 = Model(inputs = input , outputs = Output_main_model,name = 'model_main')
cat_model_at_stage_2 = Model(inputs = input , outputs = Output_cat_model ,name = 'cat_breeds_model')
dog_model_at_stage_2 = Model(inputs = input , outputs = Output_dog_model ,name = 'dog_breeds_model')

# plot_model(model_at_stage_1,show_shapes=1)
```

So, here are data and models for this hybrid model, ***How can I merge them to create a hybrid model shown in figure?***

**Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.**

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `Keras` directly allows this form of control flow as part of the computation graph. This is because the control flow APIs such as `tf.case` and other similar conditional statements in tensorflow work on output values of tensors. One way of doing this would be to setup 3 models, individually train them and then during inference, use a conditional loop to setup the control flow of data through the 3 models. However, since you are trying to build a `stacked` classifier of sorts, why not just build a multi-output classifier with `2 losses`? (or maybe a `custom loss`?)

You can define a `binary_crossentropy` for the 1st output for predicting the animal and a `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` for the 2nd output for predicting the breed. And you can set the loss weights to 60-40 or some other ration to ensure which output is prioritized by how much.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

#Model architecture
inp = layers.Input((500,500,3))
x = layers.Conv2D(10, 3)(inp)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(10, 3)(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(10, 3)(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D(3)(x)
x1 = layers.Flatten()(x)
out1 = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='animal')(x1)
x2 = layers.Conv2D(10, 3)(x)
x2 = layers.MaxPool2D(3)(x2)
x2 = layers.Flatten()(x2)
out2 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='breed')(x2)

model = Model(inp, [out1, out2])

utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=False)
```

[image]

```
images = np.random.random((100,500,500,3))
animal = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,))
breed = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,))

model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy','sparse_categorical_crossentropy'], 
              loss_weights=[0.6, 0.4], 
              optimizer='adam')

model.fit(images, [animal, breed], batch_size=8, epochs=3)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
13/13 [==============================] - 4s 324ms/step - loss: 1.3445 - animal_loss: 0.6991 - breed_loss: 2.3125
Epoch 2/3
13/13 [==============================] - 4s 314ms/step - loss: 1.3055 - animal_loss: 0.6673 - breed_loss: 2.2627
Epoch 3/3
13/13 [==============================] - 4s 322ms/step - loss: 1.2806 - animal_loss: 0.6556 - breed_loss: 2.2182
```

Comment: Nice answer. Myself included when I thought about this, only the multi-output logic came into my mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort & awesome answer. I appericaited it.

Comment: Is it possible to make a conditional layer [using switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854179/keras-tensorflow-backend-conditional-assignment-with-k-switch/52854474#52854474)

Comment: @ashraful16, as per my understanding, for [switch_case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/switch_case), or [@tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) (which is the more efficient way to write python control flow and turn it into tf control flow), you need to pass instantiated models as part of the functions. That means you will end up doing the same thing as creating 3 models, pass them through a function with control flow.

Comment: Also, think about it, early on the confidence in predictions of the base model (cats, dogs) is extremely low early on since the model has not learned. During that time, using a control flow to pass incorrectly predicted samples into the secondary branch networks for DOGS/CATS to train it will not end up reducing the loss for it. If you are trying to build a model for `hierarchical classification` you will get better results with a multi-output network or try some architecture from a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.11105.pdf) that specifically tries to solve for it.